# Site running on localhost on desktop is unreachable on android device

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, android, localhost

I'll test a website on my Android phone. For this I've shut down my firewall on my Windows 10 desktop and tried to browse to my desktop IP address 192.168.0.168 on my Android device. The port number is 4200, so the URL I've tried is `http://192.168.0.168:4200`.

The problem is that the browser I'm using said that the site can't be reached. The smartphone and desktop are on the same wifi network.

The site is reachable on my own desktop on the address `http://localhost:4200`.

I've done a ping command from my Android device with a terminal and the ping commands could reach my desktop. So what's the problem with my network?

Comment: Please forgive me for asking an obvious question... but are you running a properly configured web server on the computer?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: I've running the server with the command `ng serve` using Angular-CLI. I don't know if you got knowledge of Angular-CLI but I've done nothing else _(except shutting down my firewall)_.

Comment: does your wifi have Client/AP Isolation enabled? This setting (designed to protect wireless clients from attempting to hack or spy on each other) will make it impossible to access another LAN system from a wifi connected device.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: It think that the command `ng serve` isn't a properly configuration webserver because if I start a react application using `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start --root .`, well the site is reachable from my Android device on port 8081.

Comment: @FrankThomas: I don't know what that is but the issue is solved. See comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that the command `ng serve` *(this is the command witch I've run my site)* isn't a properly configuration webserver because if I start a React application using `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start --root .`, the site is reachable from my Android device on port 8081.

So I'm know that there aren't issues on the network and it's the webserver of Angular-CLI is bad configured.

Thanks to @JeffZeitlin for his comment.

Comment: Continuing question on Stack Overflow: [How to run my Angular site on mobile device that is running localhost on my windows desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071535/how-to-run-my-angular-site-on-mobile-device-that-is-running-localhost-on-my-wind)